# Timer (callback) inside a revealing module to update public property

Tags: javascript, callback, setinterval, revealing-module-pattern

Im attempting to get a callback working inside a module in order to update a property. In this case I just want it to toggle the property value, and would like to be able to see that externally.

Here is the simple module

```js
var Module = (function () {


    // private
    var isLoaded=false;
    var timer = null;

    var _privateMethod = function () {
        console.log('hello from private')
    }

    //public
    var publicMethod = function(){
        console.log('in public method')
        _privateMethod();
    }

    var start = function(){
        console.log('starting timer')
        timer = setInterval( function() {
            console.log('timer callback')
            isLoaded = !isLoaded;
        },1000)
    }

    var stop = function(){
        console.log('stopping timer')
        clearInterval(timer)
    }

    return {
        publicMethod: publicMethod,
        isLoaded: isLoaded,
        start: start,
        stop: stop,
    }

})();

module.exports = Module;
```

and im testing it with this

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
  }

var DM = require('./module.js')

DM.publicMethod()
DM.start()

console.log(DM.isLoaded)
 sleep(500)

console.log(DM.isLoaded)
 sleep(500)

console.log(DM.isLoaded)
 sleep(500)

console.log(DM.isLoaded)
 sleep(500)

 DM.stop();
```

It doesnt toss an error, and it looks like its starting the timer ok but im never getting the output from the callback and the property isnt updating. Im guessing its a scope issues, but I cant put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this (with that general structure), you have two options:

#### Keep the object

Keep a reference to the object you return:

```
var obj;

// ...

obj = {
    publicMethod: publicMethod,
    isLoaded: false,
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
};
return obj;
```

...and remove the `isLoaded` variable, and instead set `obj.isLoaded = true` in the callback.

Live example:

```js
var Module = (function() {
    var obj;
    var timer = null;

    var start = function(){
        console.log('starting timer')
        timer = setInterval( function() {
            console.log('timer callback')
            obj.isLoaded = !obj.isLoaded;
        },1000)
    };

    var stop = function(){
        console.log('stopping timer')
        clearInterval(timer)
    };
    
    obj = {
        //publicMethod: publicMethod,
        isLoaded: false,
        start: start,
        stop: stop,
    };
    return obj;
})();
Module.start();

var t = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Module.isLoaded = " + Module.isLoaded);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Stopping");
  clearInterval(t);
  Module.stop();
}, 10000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

### Use an accessor property:

This has the advantage of being read-only:

```
return {
    publicMethod: publicMethod,
    get isLoaded() {
        return isLoaded;
    },
    start: start,
    stop: stop,
};
```

Live example:

```js
var Module = (function() {
    var isLoaded = false;
    var timer = null;

    var start = function(){
        console.log('starting timer')
        timer = setInterval( function() {
            console.log('timer callback')
            isLoaded = !isLoaded;
        },1000)
    };

    var stop = function(){
        console.log('stopping timer')
        clearInterval(timer)
    };
    
    obj = {
        //publicMethod: publicMethod,
        get isLoaded() {
            return isLoaded;
        },
        start: start,
        stop: stop,
    };
    return obj;
})();
Module.start();

var t = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Module.isLoaded = " + Module.isLoaded);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Stopping");
  clearInterval(t);
  Module.stop();
}, 10000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: since you noted "with same general structure", I'd just like to add that im not married to this structure, i just mostly dont know what im doing and this was what i came up with from reading. It will actually be used with a BeagleBone to read the pins, so when a switch changes state I'd like the property to automatically update. Im going to run with this since its great info, but if that info gives you any other ideas I would love to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: I've run in to a snag with this. I have two files setup for this (treating the "Module" as a file. However If i take your examples, split them and export Module the code doesnt work, however if i paste it in to a single file it works fine.

Comment: @jrich523: You're never calling `M.start`. If you do, it works: https://repl.it/repls/PleasingWellmadeDigit

Comment: @jrich523: Re structure: Node modules are *already* in a private scope, so there's no need for the module pattern at all. Just export by setting properties on `exports`: https://repl.it/repls/PleasingWellmadeDigit

Comment: @jrich523: repl.it seems to have used the same URL for both of those. Here's the first one: https://repl.it/repls/WaryNativeResearch (the second is writing directly to exports re the later comment).